# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

What is wrong with this code?

```
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H: |-16-[v0]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views:["v0" : thumbnailImageView]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V: |-16-[v0]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views:["v0" : thumbnailImageView]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H: |[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views:["v0" : sepratorView]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V: [v0(1)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views:["v0" : sepratorView]))
```

I am getting an error saying 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Expected a view 
H: |-16-[v0]-16-|

Comment: Try to remove whitespaces

Comment: Thanks. It worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have extra space after H:, it must be H:|-16-[v0]-16-| . please attention to spaces and dashes and characters.